# Index Lucene: How to get PointValues terms for LongPoint field

Tags: java, lucene

I'm looking for resolution how to get terms for indexed PointValues by field name. For String it is very simple (my sample code):

```
    IndexReader reader = caseIndexer.getIndexReader();

    Fields fields = MultiFields.getFields(reader);
    Iterator<String> names = fields.iterator();
    Map<String, Terms> map = new HashMap<>();
    while (names.hasNext()) {
        String name = names.next();
        // logger.info("->>fieldName: {}", name);
        Terms terms = fields.terms(name);
        map.put(name, terms);
        TermsEnum termsEnum = terms.iterator();
        BytesRef text;
        while ((text = termsEnum.next()) != null) {
            System.out.println("field=" + name + "; text=" + text.utf8ToString());
        }
    }
```

I know how to get simple statistics like max and min value (sample code):

```
    List<FieldInfo> allFields = new ArrayList<>();
    for (LeafReaderContext ctx : reader.leaves()) {
        LeafReader lr = ctx.reader();
        Iterator<FieldInfo> infos = lr.getFieldInfos().iterator();
        PointValues values = lr.getPointValues();
        while (infos.hasNext()) {
            FieldInfo info = infos.next();
            allFields.add(info);

            if (DocValuesType.SORTED_NUMERIC.equals(info.getDocValuesType())) {

                final int numDimensions = values.getNumDimensions(info.name);
                final int numBytesPerDimension = values.getBytesPerDimension(info.name);
                byte[] leafMinValue = values.getMinPackedValue(info.name);
                long size = values.size(info.name);
                byte[] leafMaxValue = values.getMaxPackedValue(info.name);
                long minValueLong = NumericUtils.sortableBytesToLong(leafMinValue, 0);
                long maxValueLong = NumericUtils.sortableBytesToLong(leafMaxValue, 0);
                double minValueDouble = NumericUtils.sortableLongToDouble(minValueLong);
                System.out.println("field=" + info.name + "; minValueLong=" + minValueLong + "; maxValueLong="
                        + maxValueLong + "; minValueDouble=" + minValueDouble + "; numDimensions=" + numDimensions
                        + "; numBytesPerDimension=" + numBytesPerDimension + "; size=" + size);

            }
        }

    }
```

but how to get terms for points?

Comment: so you wanna get the origin value back?

Comment: yes, I wanna get the origin value back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to get the origin value of a LongPoint Field you need to store the value into a dedicated StoredField as described in [LongPoint Field JavaDoc](https://lucene.apache.org/core/7_2_0/core/org/apache/lucene/document/LongPoint.html).

In general: Point (range/exact use cases) and DocValues (sorting use cases) fields are used for specific internal lucene usage and the values are not usable for search return values.